# Android Google Map KMZ/KML Loading Really Slow

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to loads some KMZ/KML (I tryed both) in my Google Map MapView instance.
But they load really slow, they are 8 KMZ of around 300KB each and for each one it takes more than 3/4 seconds to get loaded.

How can I solve this?

Surfing in search of a solution I found they suggest to use the V3 version because it fix a polyline creation cycle really time consuming in V2.
This is the library:

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils-v3:1.3.1'
```

The problem is that when I use this library the constructors of KmlLayer stop working because inside the class KmlLayer it doesn't found the following package of the GoogleMap class, so because all the constructors require a GoogleMap instance they stop working:

```
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.GoogleMap;
```

How can I solve this? Is using the V3 version a solution to my problem? If no how can I solve this?

I found other people having the same problem but when they load KML of 10MB or more and not of just 300KB...

This is the class where there is the MapView instance:

```
public class MappaNuovoGuastoFragment extends Fragment
        implements  OnMapReadyCallback,
                    GetLocationManager.OnLocationUpdateCallback,
                    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
                    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
                    BaseRetrofitHelper.INetworkResponseCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MappaNuovoGuastoFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    // Requests Codes - Permission
    private static final int REQ_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 0xB01;
    // Requests Codes - Networking
    private static final int REQ_CODE_PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE = 0x1;
    private static final int REQ_CODE_GET_PLACE_DETAIL = 0x2;

    @BindView(R.id.ll_search)
    protected LinearLayout mllSearch;
    @BindView(R.id.actv_search_field)
    protected AutoCompleteTextView mactvSearchField;
    @BindView(R.id.map_view)
    protected MapView mMapView;

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private GetLocationManager mGetLocationManager;
    private LatLng mMyLocation;
    private LatLng mClickedLocation;
    private Marker mMarker;
    private List<GoogleMapPlace> mPlaces;

    public static MappaNuovoGuastoFragment newInstance(){
        return new MappaNuovoGuastoFragment();
    }

    //region [#] Override Lifecycle Methods
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mappa_nuovo_guasto, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        initOnCreateView(savedInstanceState);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQ_PERMISSION_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0x0) {
                for (int res : grantResults) {
                    if (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
        mGetLocationManager.startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mGetLocationManager.stopLocationUpdates();
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onDestroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Actions Methods
    @OnClick(R.id.ib_search)
    void onClickSearch(View view){
        GoogleMapPlace place = null;
        if(mPlaces != null && !mPlaces.isEmpty()){
            for(GoogleMapPlace p : mPlaces){
                if(p.getDescription().equals(mactvSearchField.getText().toString())){
                    place = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(place != null){
            requestPlaceDetails(place.getPlaceId());
        } else {
           showSnackbarLocationNotFound();
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.b_make)
    void onClickMake(View view){
        if(mClickedLocation != null || mMyLocation != null){
            startActivityGeneraGuasto();
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.b_map_type)
    void onClickMapType(View view){
        if(mGoogleMap != null){
            switch (mGoogleMap.getMapType()){
                case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE:
                case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID:
                case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE:
                    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    break;
                case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL:
                case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN:
                    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Override OnMapReadyCallback Methods
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        initGoogleMap();
        loadKmz();
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Override GetLocationManager.OnLocationUpdateCallback Methods
    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdated(@Nullable Location location) {
        if(mMyLocation == null){
            mMyLocation = location != null ? new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()) : null;
            if(mMyLocation != null){
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMyLocation, 16.0f));
            }
        } else {
            mMyLocation = location != null ? new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()) : null;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Override GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener Methods
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
        mClickedLocation = latLng;
        initMark();
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Override GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener Methods
    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
        if(mClickedLocation != null && PositionUtils.distanceBetween(mClickedLocation.latitude, mClickedLocation.longitude, latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude) <= 100){
            mClickedLocation = null;
            mMarker.remove();
            mMarker = null;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Override BaseRetrofitHelper.INetworkResponseCallback Methods
    @Override
    public void onNetworkResponseSuccess(int requestCode, Object answer) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQ_CODE_PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE:
                if(answer != null){
                    mPlaces = ((GoogleApiPlaceAutocompleteResponse)answer).getPlaces();
                    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(GoogleMapPlace place : mPlaces){
                        strings.add(place.getDescription());
                    }
                    ((ArrayAdapter<String>)mactvSearchField.getAdapter()).clear();
                    ((ArrayAdapter<String>)mactvSearchField.getAdapter()).addAll(strings);
                }
                break;
            case REQ_CODE_GET_PLACE_DETAIL:
                if(answer != null){
                    LatLng latlng = ((GoogleApiPlaceDetailsResponse)answer).getResult().getLatLng();
                    onMapClick(latlng);
                    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15));
                } else {
                    showSnackbarLocationNotFound();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkResponseError(int requestCode, Throwable t) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQ_CODE_GET_PLACE_DETAIL:
                showSnackbarLocationNotFound();
                break;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region [#] Private Methods
    private void initOnCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(requireActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        mGetLocationManager = GetLocationManager.initInstance(requireActivity()).setCallback(this);
        initAutocompleteTextView();
        mllSearch.bringToFront();
    }

    private void initGoogleMap(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, REQ_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        } else {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    }

    private void initMark(){
        if(mMarker != null){
            mMarker.remove();
        }
        LatLng pos = new LatLng(mClickedLocation.latitude, mClickedLocation.longitude);
        MarkerOptions opt = new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(getString(R.string.label_nuovo_guasto));
        opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_mark_work));
        mMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(opt);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 16.0f));
        if (mMarker != null) {
            mMarker.showInfoWindow();
        }

    }

    private void initAutocompleteTextView(){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, new ArrayList<>());
        mactvSearchField.setThreshold(0x4);
        mactvSearchField.setAdapter(adapter);
        mactvSearchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().length() >= 0x4){
                    requestPlaceAutocomplete(s.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startActivityGeneraGuasto(){
        startActivity(GeneraGuastoActivity.getIntent(requireContext(), mClickedLocation != null ? mClickedLocation.latitude : mMyLocation.latitude, mClickedLocation != null ? mClickedLocation.longitude : mMyLocation.longitude));
    }

    private void showSnackbarLocationNotFound(){
        DesignUtils.showSnackbar(mactvSearchField, getString(R.string.error_location_not_found), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    //region [#] Requests Methods
    private void requestPlaceAutocomplete(String input){
        String key = getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
        String components = String.format("country:%1$s", ((TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getNetworkCountryIso());
        TicketRetrofitHelper.getInstance().requestAsyncGetPlaceAutocomplete(TicketConstants.URL_GOOGLE_API_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE, key, input, components, REQ_CODE_PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE, this);
    }

    private void requestPlaceDetails(String idPlace){
        String key = getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
        TicketRetrofitHelper.getInstance().requestAsyncGetPlaceDetails(TicketConstants.URL_GOOGLE_API_PLACE_DETAILS, key, idPlace, REQ_CODE_GET_PLACE_DETAIL, this);
    }
    //endregion

    private void loadKmz(){
        try {
            KmlLayer kmz1 = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.centri_abitati_1, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz2  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.centri_abitati_2, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz3  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.confini_comuni_1, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz4  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.confini_comuni_2, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz5  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.viabilita_1, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz6  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.viabilita_2, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz7  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.viabilita_3, requireContext());
            KmlLayer kmz8  = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, R.raw.viabilita_4, requireContext());

            kmz1.addLayerToMap();
            kmz2.addLayerToMap();
            kmz3.addLayerToMap();
            kmz4.addLayerToMap();
            kmz5.addLayerToMap();
            kmz6.addLayerToMap();
            kmz7.addLayerToMap();
            kmz8.addLayerToMap();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //endregion


}
```

Comment: Which implementation did you use for V2?

Comment: This:
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'